# Simple Jquery Gallery Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I am new to Jquery and and trying to build a simple gallery. I know there is lots of plugins, but I don't want to use any of them. my question is very simple. how can I fade in image when click on thumb. also how can I achieve auto fadeIn and Out. I will really appreciate any response. thanks

here is my code.

//HTML

```
<div class="LargeImage">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="thumbsImages">
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

// JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var LargeImages = $(".LargeImages").children();
    var SmallImages = $(".thumbsImages").children();


    SmallImages.each(function() {

        SmallImages.click(function() {

            LargeImages.each(function() {

                // I have problem here with logic           
            });

            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to call `SmallImages.click(...)` within the `SmallImages.each(...)`, you'll end up hooking the `click` event on each image multiple times. (`click` hooks the handler up to *all* matching elements inside the jQuery instance you call it on.)

Here's a basic way to do what you're doing without the extra `div`s:

HTML:

```
<div class="LargeImage">
</div>
<div class="thumbsImages">
<img class="thumb"
     src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'
     data-fullsize='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=123&d=identicon&r=PG'>
<img class="thumb"
     src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/92e9e88f33ab596fa1caaf237a4d5fad?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'
     data-fullsize='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/92e9e88f33ab596fa1caaf237a4d5fad?s=123&d=identicon&r=PG'>
<img class="thumb"
     src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c3203aa647aeb214c463c59f1af2c38f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'
     data-fullsize='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c3203aa647aeb214c463c59f1af2c38f?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG'>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Look up the large image once and remember it
  var largeImage = $(".LargeImage");

  // Hook the click event on the thumbnails
  $(".thumbsImages img").click(function() {
    var fullsize, hasImage;

    // Get the full size version from the attribute
    fullsize = $(this).attr("data-fullsize");

    // Flag up whether there's current an image in the large area
    hasImage = largeImage.find('img').length == 0;

    // Fade out whatever's there, then fade in the new image;
    // the `hasImage` check just makes the fadeOut really fast if
    // there's nothing showing.
    largeImage.fadeOut(hasImage ? 0 : 250, function() {
      largeImage.html("<img src='" + fullsize + "'>").fadeIn(250);
    });

  });

});​
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eveko3)

Basically, what I'm doing there is storing the URL of the full size version in the `img` element for the thumbnail as `data-fullsize` (the `data-` prefix means that the attribute will validate under HTML5; prior to HTML5 there's no official way to have your own attributes, but browsers allow it even though it's technically invalid). Then, when the user clicks an image, we fade out whatever's showing in the big div, then replace it with the full-size image and fade in.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I just do not want to set the image scr with each click on thumb. I want to fade the div. my Aim is to get the idea, that how to match up the index() of both. so that I can play around with the div. like to add some more contents to that Div.

Comment: @user: Did you run the example? It **is** fading the div. I think if you play with it, you'll get there.

Comment: Thanks @Crowder @Jayme for your time. i fixed the issue now. 

Here is the code for it.
    $(".LargeImages .div:not(.active)").fadeOut(300);                  //hide initially
    $(".LargeImages .div:first(.active)").fadeIn(300);

    $(".thumbsImages").click(function () {

        $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');

        $(".LargeImages .div").fadeOut().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(300);

    });

but now how can i make it auto fadeIn and fadeOut. and when it fadeIn from one to another, how can I hight the thumb aswell. Thanks

Comment: how about if I want to add next and previous button. any idea how to do this please.

Comment: @Eager: I recommend you post a new question to ask that.

Comment: Yes i asked a new question, here is the post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013373/jquery-simple-gallery

Answer (score 0):

An idea of what you should do:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.thumbsImages').click(function()
    {
    var index = $('.active').prevAll('div').length; //number of previous siblings
    $('.LargeImage').find('div:eq('+index+')').fadeOut(500); //hide the actual showed element

    $('.active').removeClass("active"); //remove the active class
            $(this).addClass("active"); //add class to the actual clicked item

            index = $(this).prevAll('div').length; //number of previous siblings
    $('.LargeImage').find('div:eq('+index+')').fadeIn(500); //show the actual selected image
    });
});
```

It's not a really optimized code. But it's simple to understand. ;)

I don't know if it's what you´re needing, but I hope it helps!

Comment: but this didn't worked for me. I have already implemented something like this. it didn't work in IE and chrome. but only work in firfox.

Here is the code for it.

            $(".thumbsImages").click(function() {
                $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current'); //<li> portion
                
                $(".LargeImage .div").fadeOut()

                .eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();

            });​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Man! I hate webkit!!! ><
It's strange, for me it worked fine... even in webkit and IE.. =/
For example, in the galleries here: http://dev.doois.com.br/ellus/
I've done some code similar in it and it works fine.

Inspect the code on chrome, sometimes it renders the html different from what we've written. But it's safari the worst one!